# How can I format Search output in zerobane studio

Tags: configuration, format

Would like the output of my searches to be really visible in zerobane studio.

I am using the default `tomorrow.lua | tomorrowNight` theme.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the `Selection` variable in the `tomorrow.lua` file.